# How to use a Group by pipe with as a grouping key a specific date format

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of data :

```
  players  = [{name: 'Gene', team: 'team alpha', date: '2019-09-18T16:45:42' },
              {name: 'Steve', team: 'team gamma', date: '2019-09-18T15:45:42'},
              {name: 'George', team: 'team beta', date: '2019-20-18T12:45:42'},
              {name: 'Paula', team: 'team beta', date: '2019-18-18T15:45:42'},
              {name: 'Jhon', team: 'team gamma', date: '2019-09-18T15:45:42'}];
```

}

I would like to use a grouping pipe that is only on the date but instead of the format '2019-09-18T15: 45: 42', it should be done only on the following format '2019-09-18' which is more consistent to group.

here is the pipe used :

```
  @Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
   export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(collection: Array<any>, property: string): Array<any> {
     if(!collection) {
        return null;
     }

    const groupedCollection = collection.reduce((previous, current)=> {
        if(!previous[current[property]]) {
            previous[current[property]] = [current];
        } else {
            previous[current[property]].push(current);
        }

        return previous;
    }, {});

    return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedCollection[key] }));
  }
}
```

and the html :

```
 <ul>
   <div *ngFor="let player of players | groupBy:'date'"> Team : {{player.key}}
     <li *ngFor="let eachplayer of player.value">
  {{eachplayer.name}}
    </li>
   </div>
</ul>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2ve9k?file=src/app/app.component.html

I think a reprocessing of the date like this would be convenient but I do not know where I could use it

```
   date.split('T')[0];
```

I am listening to your solution proposals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the date of your collection before grouping it:

```
  @Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
   export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(collection: Array<any>, property: string): Array<any> {
     if(!collection) {
        return null;
     }

    const mappedCollection = collection.map(player => ({
                               ...player, 
                               date: player.date.split('T')[0]
                             }));

    const groupedCollection = mappedCollection.reduce((previous, current)=> {
        if(!previous[current[property]]) {
            previous[current[property]] = [current];
        } else {
            previous[current[property]].push(current);
        }

        return previous;
    }, {});

    return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedCollection[key] }));
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a statement error in your solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phljal?file=src/app/group.pipe.ts

Comment: I changed your solution by  :  const mappedCollection = collection.map(elt => ({ ...elt, date :elt.date.split('T')[0]}))